# Alexa smart home skill development: Device discovery not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently developing a smart home skill for my blinds, however I am unable to discover device. Is there a way for me to validate my Discovery response message? I'm thinking this is some logical error in the JSON.

I'm using a Lambda function to perform the requests to my API using node-fetch and async/await, thus I have tagged all JS function as async, this could be another potential cause of this issue. I don't get any errors in CloudWatch either.

This is the response my Lambda function is sending:

```
{
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
            "name": "Discover.Response",
            "payloadVersion": "3",
            "messageId": "0a58ace0-e6ab-47de-b6af-b600b5ab8a7a"
        },
    "payload": {
        "endpoints": [
            {
                "endpointId": "com-tobisoft-rollos-1",
                "manufacturerName": "tobisoft",
                "description": "Office Blinds",
                "friendlyName": "Office Blinds",
                "displayCategories": [
                    "INTERIOR_BLIND"
                ],
                "capabilities": [
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa.RangeController",
                        "instance": "Blind.Lift",
                        "version": "3",
                        "properties": {
                            "supported": [
                                {
                                    "name": "rangeValue"
                                }
                            ],
                            "proactivelyReported": true,
                            "retrievable": true
                        },
                        "capabilityResources": {
                            "friendlyNames": [
                                {
                                    "@type": "asset",
                                    "value": {
                                        "assetId": "Alexa.Setting.Opening"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "configuration": {
                            "supportedRange": {
                                "minimumValue": 0,
                                "maximumValue": 100,
                                "precision": 1
                            },
                            "unitOfMeasure": "Alexa.Unit.Percent"
                        },
                        "semantics": {
                            "actionMappings": [
                                {
                                    "@type": "ActionsToDirective",
                                    "actions": [
                                        "Alexa.Actions.Close"
                                    ],
                                    "directive": {
                                        "name": "SetRangeValue",
                                        "payload": {
                                            "rangeValue": 100
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "@type": "ActionsToDirective",
                                    "actions": [
                                        "Alexa.Actions.Open"
                                    ],
                                    "directive": {
                                        "name": "SetRangeValue",
                                        "payload": {
                                            "rangeValue": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "@type": "ActionsToDirective",
                                    "actions": [
                                        "Alexa.Actions.Lower"
                                    ],
                                    "directive": {
                                        "name": "AdjustRangeValue",
                                        "payload": {
                                            "rangeValueDelta": 10,
                                            "rangeValueDeltaDefault": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "@type": "ActionsToDirective",
                                    "actions": [
                                        "Alexa.Actions.Raise"
                                    ],
                                    "directive": {
                                        "name": "AdjustRangeValue",
                                        "payload": {
                                            "rangeValueDelta": -10,
                                            "rangeValueDeltaDefault": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "stateMappings": [
                                {
                                    "@type": "StatesToValue",
                                    "states": [
                                        "Alexa.States.Closed"
                                    ],
                                    "value": 100
                                },
                                {
                                    "@type": "StatesToRange",
                                    "states": [
                                        "Alexa.States.Open"
                                    ],
                                    "range": {
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa",
                        "version": "3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to validate my Discovery response message?

Yes, you could use the [Alexa Smart Home Message JSON Schema](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-smarthome/tree/master/validation_schemas). This schema can be used for message validation during skill development, it validates Smart Home skills (except the Video Skills API).

> This is the response my Lambda function is sending

I've validated your response following [this steps](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-smarthome/wiki/Validation-Schemas#how-to-use), the result: *no errors found, the JSON validates against the schema*. So, there's probably another thing going on. I suggest getting in touch with [Alexa Developer Contact Us](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/contact-us)